# Excel same multiple values match same multiple values

Tags: excel, vlookup

Can I obtain `G` column in `table 2` with formula?

[image]

More clearly, search first 155 in A column and write first match, search second 155 in a column and write secont match...

Comment: If there are always only 2 matches, I suppose it's probably possible, but messy, but what if there are 3, 4, 5, or *n* matches?

Comment: Are you precluded from using VBA or a custom User-Defined Formula?

Comment: I need more than 10 matches. I can use userdefined formula. Thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far? This isn't a "free code for me" website, you're expected usually to demonstrate some minimal competency and effort towards solving the problem, first, and ask questions only about specific, answerable problems in your implementation.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. You are right.

Comment: I found the solution.`=IFERROR(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$10=F4;ROW($A$2:$A$10));COUNTIF($F$2:F4;F4));2));"")`

Comment: Great work!  You can "Answer" your own question here, if that solves it.

Comment: I cringe when I see INDIRECT and ADDRESS they are both volatile, and take more computation to switch the address to a string and back again.Put this in G2: `=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A;AGGREGATE(15;6;ROW($B$2:$B$10)/($A$2:$A$10=F2);COUNTIF($F$2:F2;F2)));"")` and copy down.

Comment: Or if you like your array formula SMALL: `=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A;SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$10=F4;RO‌​W($A$2:$A$10));COUNT‌​IF($F$2:F4;F4)));"")`

Comment: I cant run it  @Scott-Craner  :( The file is here :http://dosya.co/iiynbp6stuoc/soru.xlsx.html